# how to use multiple id in html while using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-selectors

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" src="ts_picker.js">


</script>
<script src="demo/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="demo/js/jquery.datePicker-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript" src="demo/js/jquery.bgiframe.min.js"></script><![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).ready(function(){
  $('#date-pick').datePicker({clickInput:true});
 $('#date-pick1').datePicker({clickInput:true});
 $('#date-pick2').datePicker({clickInput:true});
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form name="tstest">

<input type="Text" name="timestamp" value="" id="data-pick">

<a href="javascript:show_calendar('document.tstest.timestamp', document.tstest.timestamp.value);">
<img src="cal.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Click Here to Pick up the timestamp">
</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

hai in this while am using the text box it get the date properly but i want call some other javascript for the same textbox using different id if i used two ids its not working properly any one can help me to solve this problem

Comment: Don't use inline javascript. Inform your self on graceful degradation and unobstrusive javascript.

Comment: Which `id`? You code does not have/reference any `id`.

Comment: I think you have a typo in your id ... you have `$('#date-pick').datePicker({clickInput:true});` but in the form you have `<input type="Text name="timestamp" value="" id="data-pick">` ... **data-pick** and not `date-pick`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to setup different Javascript functionalities on the same element using different keywords I would suggest assigning the element different classes since you can have multiple classes but only one id per element.

for example instead of:

```
<input id="date-pick" id="some-other-thing" />
```

which is clearly wrong and bad markup go with:

```
<input class="date-pick some-other-thing" />
```

and then in your Javascript use

```
$(".date-pick").datePicker();
$(".some-other-thing").someOtherThing();
```

One thing to point out tho' is that classes do not have a uniqueness requirement and thus you can have more than one element with the same class and the above code would apply `datePicker` or `someOtherThing` functionalities to all of them.